# Extjs 4 Form submit is not workingi

Tags: extjs4

I am using Extjs 4.1.1

I have a form panel. And I am submitting the form with few parameters.

```
form.submit({
url : submit_Url,
params :{
    'svgXml':svgXml,
    'queryData':queryData,
    'gridColumns':gridColumns,
    'boname':boName,             
    'attachmentName':attachmentName,
    'reportTypeName':reportTypeName,
    'chartType':chartType,                              
    'reportCriteria':reportCriteria
},
method 
:'POST',
    success : function(form, action) {
        parent.closeExtjsModal(0);
    },
    failure :  function(form, action) 
    {
        SetError (); 
    }
});
```

and from server side I am setting {"success" :true}

but still I am getting error

```
uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): //You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:
```

Can you please explain what is the problem.??

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly the issue with the response from server. Could you verify in the browser(preferably chrome) developer tool and post the response of your submit request.